# CouchDB ACL cross referencing documents

Tags: reference, couchdb, acl

Let's say I have two types of docs with one referencing the other, e.g. "orders" and "order_replies" the later one having a field "ref" which contains an ID of an order document.

For my validate_doc_update function I want a user only to be able to change an order_reply document if he is the author of the original order.

How can I get the "author" field from the order with the ID newDoc.ref within the function?

Here's a part of my validation function so far:

```
if(userCtx.roles.indexOf('employee') >= 0) {
  // [...] other doc types
  if (newDoc.type == 'order_reply') {
    //newDoc.ref.author is not the proper approach
    require((userCtx.name == newDoc.ref.author), "this is not your order reply!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note I have added a warning in [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737285/couchdb-acl-cross-referencing-documents/6788113#6788113).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the author's ID in the order's ID. For example:

- The order: `{ "_id": "order/jack/1", ... }`
- An order's reply: `{ "ref": "order/jack/1", ... }`

So you can check with:

```
if (userCtx.roles.indexOf('employee') !== -1) {
  if (newDoc.type === 'order_reply') {
    require(userCtx.name === newDoc.ref.split('/', 3)[1], "this is not your order reply!");
  }
}
```

If you have multiple authors, use `"order/author1/author2/.../authorN/ordernum"` as `_id` of the order and check with:

```
var parts = newDoc.ref.split('/'),
    authors = parts.slice(1, -1);
require(authors.indexOf(userCtx.name) !== -1, "this is not your order reply!");
```

**UPDATE:** Due to bug [COUCHDB-1229](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1229), use of "/" in doc._id may cause problems. Depending on your use-case, it may be better to use another separator, e.g. ":".

Comment: Sadly this won't work, because there might be multiple authors, so their names cannot be part of the ID.

Comment: @vc666 I have edited the answer to allow for multiple authors. No time to test the code, sorry... hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this will have to do. But I don't get why CouchDB doesn't provide a method to retrieve docs within a function...